# Table of Occurrence of Variable With Each Other in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of different categorical variables that looks like this:

```
df:
    A    B    C    D
0   a    b    c    d
1   b    d    a    e
2   d    a    e    c
```

Each row has a variable from a-e and they are never repeated per column. I want to know and create a table of occurrence of each value with each other in a row. The desired dataframe looks like this:

```
df2:
    x   a   b   c   d   e
0   a   NaN 2   2   3   2
1   b   2   NaN 1   2   1
2   c   2   1   NaN 2   1
3   d   3   2   2   NaN 1
4   e   2   1   1   1   NaN
```

I already have `df2['x']` so I already have a column of the variables.

I was able to count the occurrence and mapped them to the corresponding variable by:

```
for x in df['x']:
    df2[str(x)] = df2['x'].map(df.melt()['value'].value_counts())

    x   a   b   c   d   e
0   a   3   2   2   3   2
1   b   2   2   1   2   1
2   c   2   1   2   2   1
3   d   3   2   2   3   1
4   e   2   1   1   1   2
```

As you can see, instead of an NaN, I'm getting the overall count of the variable when it is tabulated against itself. I'm expecting this though from the functions that used.

Is there a way to change those values to NaN? I eventually want to change them to 0 or whatever, during visualization, but having them as NaN is simpler as they are easier to find (the values are unique and the same).

Also, is there a simpler way of doing what I want as I'm iterating over each item in df2['x']?

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `dot` after `stack` and `crosstab`

```
s = df.stack()
s = pd.crosstab(s,s.index.get_level_values(0))
s = s.dot(s.T).astype(float)
np.fill_diagonal(s.values, np.nan)
s
row_0    a    b    c    d    e
row_0                         
a      NaN  2.0  2.0  3.0  2.0
b      2.0  NaN  1.0  2.0  1.0
c      2.0  1.0  NaN  2.0  1.0
d      3.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0
e      2.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
```

Comment: Final output doesn't look right. probably get values level `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

We can try a `stack` followed by `merge` and `crosstab`:

```
s = df.stack().reset_index(name='val')
s = s.merge(s, on='level_0').query('val_x!=val_y')

pd.crosstab(s.val_x, s.val_y)
```

Output:

```
val_y  a  b  c  d  e
val_x               
a      0  2  2  3  2
b      2  0  1  2  1
c      2  1  0  2  1
d      3  2  2  0  2
e      2  1  1  2  0
```